# Differences between Bonjour/Avahi/People-Nearby protocols

Tags: empathy, avahi, zeroconf

I recently discovered, through Ubuntu's empathy IM client, that exists a protocol that enables the user to talk with anyone on his actual local network. It seems empathy calls this service "People Nearby" and Windows "[People Near Me](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726969.aspx)".

After some research I discovered more information: it seems the "protocol" is called Avahi (or [Bonjour](http://www.apple.com/support/bonjour/)/Salut(?) by Apple) and permits a user to connect to users, printers and files on the network.

**My questions:**

1. Bonjour, Avahi, people nearby, people nearby... are these things different names for the same thing, i.e. to connect to "things" (users/printers/files) on the same network? Are these different implementations of Zeroconf?
2. Which IM support this kind of protocol? AIM, Trillian and Empathy support it, am I right? Which of them are usable on a smartphone (Android)? I think Trillian does and WiChat too but only for iOS.
3. Is there an Android app that implements a Bonjour's or Avahi's service for Instant Messaging?

Comment: Cross-posted the [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6160647/1591669).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bonjour is Apple's trade marked name for the Zeroconf protocols.  These protocols consist of:

1. A method of automatically assigning IP addresses to machines on the local network when no DHCP server is available.
2. A method of advertising services on the local network (service discovery over multicast DNS).

Avahi is the implementation of these protocols used by Ubuntu.

The `People Nearby` service in Empathy uses the [XMPP Serverless Messaging](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html) extension, which entails advertising your presence over the local network via the standard Zeroconf service discovery protocols, and clients sending messages to each other directly instead of via a server.

Salut is the name of the Empathy backend that implements this protocol.

To my knowledge, there isn't a standard multicast DNS implementation on Android, so I don't know whether many clients would implement this serverless messaging extension.

Comment: What about the compatibility between these protocols? Can Microsoft People Nera Me communicate with the others?

Comment: I don't know what protocol Microsoft's People Near Me uses.  I suspect it is different though.

Comment: Microsoft's "People near me" is their own soup again; it uses SOAP-over-UDP as basis. Totally incompatible.